# Form is sent only first time

Tags: html, forms, download

I have a page to download a file depending on some configuration which is in a form.

When I send the form, the file is downloaded fine, but if I change the form and send it again, nothing happens.

Example form:

```
<form action="/download" method="get" target="_blank">
  <input type="checkbox" name="some_option" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

The form is sent only the first time.

I thought about using JS for sending the form, but I don't think the file download work that way.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: Added `target="_blank"` like suggested.

UPDATE:

Added this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  this.action = addRandomParam(this.action);
  console.log(this.action);
});
```

The `submit` event is triggered every time the "Download" button is hit, but I still get the file downloaded only the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure what `action="download"` is supposed to mean. `download` should be replaced by a valid URL, relative or absolute.

Comment: Can you elaborate over sending the form again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was some Javascript doing something like this (code merely illustrative :P) ...

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  if (alreadySent()) {
    this.preventDefault();
  }
  setAsSent();
});
```

This was to prevent normal forms from being sent multiple times.

Thank you everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your download URL is `download`, you need to add a slash there, otherwise the next submission will take you to `/download/download` which obviously does not exist. If this is correct, you can try setting you action to `action="/download"`

Comment: I changed that, and even added a target="_blank".. same result.

Comment: don't think you can set `target` on forms, only on `<a>` tags. Can you  confirm that the form action is meant to be `/download` ?

Comment: The target works, it opens a new tab downloads the file and closes it. The action "/download" works fine too. The problem is when I hit "Download" again; it does nothing from the second time, no network activity, no errors, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the browser is somehow caching the url for your submission? Can you try adding a random param to the download URL AFTER hitting the submit button? That way the next time you hit submit, the browser will think it's a different url?